# Trying to allocate 3G for buffer pool in InnoDB fails

Tags: mysql, innodb, windows

I'm trying to boost my InnoDB driver on my Windows 7 PC since each page request takes just about 1.7 seconds to load versus 0.002 seconds on my Ubuntu 12.10 workstation.

The setting I'm playing around with is the well-known `innodb_buffer_pool_size` line, which should increase the performance a lot, and it did on my Ubuntu workstation - but my Windows 7 workstation can only seem to allocate 1G of RAM, my system currently have 16GB.

If I try to exceed 4GB I get `[ERROR] innobase_buffer_pool_size can't be over 4GB on 32-bit systems`, so I try to allocate 3G but now my server wont start, same goes for 2G. 1GB works but did only contribute to about 0.1s worth of speed increase - which isn't much.

Is there something more I have to account for on Windows to get better performance, and why can I not allocate more than 1G of RAM? (I get no errors when I try to allocate more than 1GB, the server just won't start)

Comment: What is the result of this query : `show variables like 'version_compile%';`

Comment: What version of MySQL ? (Please run `select version();`)

Comment: I just saw you have `innobase_buffer_pool_size`. Seriously, what version of MySQL are you running ?  (Please run `select version();`)

Comment: MySQL version 5.5.27

Comment: What is the result of this query : `show variables like 'version_compile%';`

Comment: `version_compile_machine : x86`, `version_compile_os
: Win32`. I've got a Windows 7 x64 OS, and I use XAMPP for convenience.

Comment: Is the Window7 machine running as 32-bit or 64-bit ? Click Start, Right-click Computer, Select Properties. What is the System Type ?

Comment: See my edited comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since

- `show variables like 'version_compile%';` gives you

  - `version_compile_machine : x86`
  - `version_compile_os : Win32`
- Your OS is Windows 7 x64 OS

it looks like you simply need to upgrade the version of MySQL to the 64-bit Windows version.

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: I switched to a x64 build and now the page generates in 0.07s with the buffer set to 12G! Now that is acceptable :) Thank you!